# Increase in latency of fetching data from Guava Cache

Tags: java, caching, guava

We are using Guava cache in our service.

The async scheduler updates cache every 20 minutes.
`executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable(), 0, refreshIntervalInSeconds, SECONDS);`

We have set the **initalTime** = 0. So just after deployment scheduler should start and put data in cache.
When the service fetch the data from cache just after deployment latency seems to increase by 20x.
We are using `Cache.getIfPresent()` method to get the data. So it should return null if cache is empty.

- There should be no issue with Write/Read lock as the cache refreshes every 20 mins. So in every 20 mins latency should increase which is not the case. The latency increase just  after deployment.

We are unable to think of any reasoning behind this. Can someone help us understand why this is happening ?

Cache Building:
`cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build()`

Comment: Please show the code you're creating the cache (please use `someHeavyDbOperation` instead actual logic).

Comment: @Xaerxess added

Comment: If you're querying for the key which hasn't finished loading, the call is blocked until the value is actually in the cache.

Comment: @Xaerxess Is there any way to avoid this ? We are okay with returning null when the values are not present in Cache.                                                                                        Can you also provide some reference for the above comment?

Comment: You're not using `LoadingCache`, so it should not be an issue. Could you share [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: It sounds like you are reloading the cache and it is used as a `Map`. You might instead use an `AtomicReference<Map<...>>` and replace the map every time the scheduler runs.

Comment: @BenManes How does using AtomicReference will reduce the Cache Loading time during deployment ?